# Core Plot how to make legend show just the lines plotted

Tags: core-plot, legend

I am using the same scatterplot to display either 5 or 4 lines depending upon the type of data to display. The code that puts the lines on the scatterplot is:

```
    if (typeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Hotel"]) { nums = valuesQT1; }
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Retail"]) { nums = valuesQT2; }
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Office"]) { nums = valuesQT3; }
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Industrial"]) { nums = valuesQT4; }
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Apartment"]) { nums = valuesQT5; }
     }
     else {
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"East"]) { nums = valuesQR1; }
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"South"]) { nums = valuesQR2; }
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Midwest"]) { nums = valuesQR3; }
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"West"]) { nums = valuesQR4; }
    }
```

So the legend should show the swatches and labels for Hotel, Retail, Office, Industrial, and Apartment when the typeSelector is 0, and should show the swatches and labels for East, South, Midwest, and West when the typeSelector is 1.

All the scatterplots use the same line chart:

```
    lineChart = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    linePlotView.hostedGraph = lineChart;
```

Each data set is added to the lineChart with:

```
    [lineChart addPlot:amtPlot1];
    [lineChart addPlot:amtPlot2];
    [lineChart addPlot:amtPlot3];
```

et cetera.

The label code is as follows:

```
    // Add legend
    if (typeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        CPTLegend *theLegend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:lineChart];
        theLegend.swatchSize = CGSizeMake(30.0, 20.0);
        CPTMutableTextStyle *blackTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
        blackTextStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
        blackTextStyle.fontSize = 12.0;
        theLegend.numberOfRows = 5;
        lineChart.legend = theLegend;
        lineChart.legend.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];
        lineChart.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorLeft;
        lineChart.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(100.0, 0.0);
    }
```

This works perfectly for the first set of 5 lines on the scatterplot. However, when I use similar code on the second set of 4 lines, the legend swatches and labels from the first set show along with the second set.

I just want a legend with 5 swatches and labels for the first set and a legend with 4 swatches and labels for the second set.

Is this possible without having to create two separate charts like lineChart1 (for the first 5) and lineChart2 (for the second 4)?

Comment: Here's a kludge but it works. I remove the first 5 plots prior to displaying the legend of the second set of 4 plots as follows:

        if (typeSelector.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
            [lineChart removePlot:amtPlot1];
            [lineChart removePlot:amtPlot2];
            [lineChart removePlot:amtPlot3];
            [lineChart removePlot:amtPlot4];
            [lineChart removePlot:amtPlot5];

Comment: Are all nine plots always in the graph?

Comment: Eric, the plots show in a 5 set group and a 4 set group depending upon the typeSelector value, but the labels for all 9 are apparently retained for legend display purposes. The labels for the legends, as you know, are found in the plot.identifier text. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

The `+legendWithGraph:` method builds a legend using all of the plots that have been added to the graph prior to it being called. If you call it on the graph without first removing the unwanted plots, they *will* appear in the legend. I see several options:

1. Remove plots from the graph when not using them, as noted in your comment, and create a new legend as needed.
2. Create the legend using `+legendWithPlots:` instead. Pass an array of the plots that you want represented in the legend.
3. `CPTLegend` has `-addPlot:` and `-removePlot:` methods similar to the ones in `CPTGraph`. Use them to update an existing legend as needed rather than creating a new legend every time.